# MDic installation

Tags: installation

I've downloaded MDic dictionary from [1]: http://mdic.gnufolks.org/ but I don't know how to install it. The file has named as mdic-0.8.1.tar.gz 
Please guide me to install.

Comment: The archive contains a `README` file with a `Compile/Install` section. Have you followed that? Also note that this application hasn't been updated since early 2010. Compiling/installing on a distribution released more than three years later may not be very straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the tar.gz and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic qt4-dev-tools qt4-qmake libaspell-dev  
cd mdic
mkdir build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
```

You may find that the install process will stop complaining about missing packages. If so, open Synaptic or Software Manager and install the -dev version of the missing package. After the cmake gets to "..-- Build files have been written.." then proceed to:

```
make
sudo make install
```

I got this package to 'make' on my 13.04 system without any error or warning (!!) but did not install it.

Comment: Why install with `/usr` as the prefix? Isn't it better to use `/usr/local` (which is usually the default) to avoid conflicts if any of the same files are currently, or ever will be, provided by an Ubuntu package)?

Comment: Because that's what the README says to do.